# sync vertical scroll bar of jqgrid with other div vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am new in jqgrid. I want to sync the vertical scroll  bar of jqgrid with other div vertical scroll. i tried more example but no one being helpful. 
So, please provide me appropriate solution as soon as possible
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you specify what you mean under "sync vertical scroll bar"? Could you describe more details what problem exist and what you expect as the goal? Some pictures would be welcome. If you have not yet the right to include the picture then you can upload it somewhere and include the URL to the picture. I (or some other readers) will include the picture directly in the text your question.

Comment: i have a div of id="scrl" and a jqgrid of id="list". The overflow of scrl is:auto.  And i want when i am scrolling the div 'scrl' vertically then the jqgrid scroll vertical  automatically totally depend upon div 'scrl' scroll.

Comment: Which relation have div of id="scrl" and a jqgrid of id="list"? Is the div is outer div of jqGrid #list or at least have the div and the grid jqGrid #list the same height? If the div is outer div then you can just set `overflow: hidden`. It's really difficult to understand the problem without to see the corresponding picture or having more detailed description.